# Possible to figure out whose go it is in checkers game, based purely on the position of pieces on the board?

Tags: combinatorics

I came across a checkers board in my house with an unfinished game on it which made me wonder if it possible, just by looking at the positions of the pieces on the board, whose go it is next. For example, this is impossible in chess (I.e. There are plenty of positions which come to mind where it is impossible to determine who goes next.)I was wondering if it is the same for checkers. I feel that it should be determinable but I'm not sure. I tried to prove it by numbering the rows of the checkers board and assigning values to each piece based on the row the piece is in, and created a semi-successful system where different positions could be described as even or odd, each indicating a different player to move next. That said, the system failed to work in some situations (capturing wasn't properly accounted for). Of course, if someone can come up with a counter example, that would solve the problem. Does anyone have any ideas for how to solve a question like this? Many thanks!

Comment: Until kings come into play, you can pretty easily figure out how many moves each player has taken by adding up the rows of all the pieces, and subtracting the starting rows and the total number of jumps made. After kings come into play, you couldn't get the exact number of moves, but since the only ways to get back to a previous position in an odd number of turns involve jumps, you should still be able to get an even/odd scheme to work.

Comment: On second thought, that doesn't properly account for double jumps.

Comment: @genisage yeah it's impossible to tell the difference between two single-jumps and one double-jump (you can "waste a move" by taking two single-jumps)

Comment: It should be noted that there are [quite a few](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draughts) flavours of checkers so you might want to state which rule set you have in mind.

Comment: @genisage Note that, in my example below, there are no kings, the the number of jumps is the same in both variations. The point is, if a checker is missing, there is no way of telling how many time it moved before it was jumped.

Answer (score 0):

I have a counterexample.

[image]

suppose both sides have that sort of situation somewhere on the board and it's red's move. Then red can make a double jump followed by 4 moves to take both blues and get back (5 moves) or two single jumps followed by 4 moves to get to the same position in 6 moves.
If blue chooses to do it in 5 moves, then depending on whether red does it in 5 or 6 moves, it could either be blue's or red's move when they're both back in their original positions and you have no way to tell.
**EDIT:** As @bof pointed out, my initial intuition was incorrect, and it's impossible even without kings or double jumps.

Comment: If it's red's move in that position, the double jump is mandatory.

Comment: really? I think that's a house rules thing. But I'm definitely not a checkers expert.

Comment: Interesting counterexample! Thanks. So I suppose if we play with rules which don't require you to take pieces when you can, it is impossible to always determine whose go it is. I wonder if it is still the same in a situation where you must take pieces whenever possible

Answer (score 0):

The game starts with the 12 white men on the black squares of the bottom three rows, and the 12 black men on the black squares of the top three rows. White is moving up the board, Black is moving down the board; as usual in checkers, Black moves first. I will use chess notation instead of checkers notation for the squares, because I think more people are familiar with that.

Note that the following two games arrive at the same position, but with different players on the move:

$\ \ $ Black White
1. h6-g5 c3-d4
2. g7-h6 a3-b4
3. h8-g7 b4-c5
4. d6-b4 g3-h4
5. b4-a3 h2-g3

$\ \ $ Black White
1. d6-c5 a3-b4
2. c5-a3 c3-d4
3. h6-g5 g3-h4
4. g7-h6 h2-g3
5. h8-g7